# Split delimited string/cell value into multiple rows

Tags: python, csv, import-from-csv

I can solve this problem in many ways, but I want to use Python.  Here is the question:

I have a CSV file which contains values like so:

```
Name         Address                 Skills

Napoleon     Preston, Idaho          Bowhunting, Computer Hacking, Drawing Unicorns
```

I want to transform it to this:

```
Name         Address                 Skill 
Napoleon     Preston, Idaho          Bowhunting
Napoleon     Preston, Idaho          Computer Hacking
Napoleon     Preston, Idaho          Drawing Unicorns
```

I have researched, and I've read up on the CSV library, but I feel like I'll end up doing something very ugly and overly complicated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: please add what have you tried so far.

Comment: Is it always of the form:  `name city, state      skill1, skill2, skill3, ...`?   In other words, Are you guaranteed that there is a city *and a state* and that they're always separated by a comma?

Comment: If you need a Python program to do this the answer below is great. If you just want some one-off csv processing take a look at csvkit, which is a set of command line tools for manipulating csv files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you have a flat file, I believe the first step to manipulating your data is to load it into python so that you can begin to use it.

You're on the right track.  The csv module was designed for this

Assuming your data is tab separated

```
import csv

with open('your_csv.csv') as f:
  f.readline() # these are headings should remove them
  csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
  for line_list in csv_reader:
     # line_list is a list of each row of your csv       
     # line_list[0] Contains 'Name' data   'Napolean'
     # line_list[1] Cotinas Address 'Preston, Idaho'
     # line_list[2] Contains skills 'Bowhunting, Computer Hacking, Drawing Unicorns'
     skills_list = [x.strip() for x in line_list[2].split(',')]
     for skill in skills_list:
        #line_list[0]   line_list[1],   skill


        Napoleon     Preston, Idaho          Bowhunting
        Napoleon     Preston, Idaho          Computer Hacking
        Napoleon     Preston, Idaho          Drawing Unicorns
```

Comment: To ignore the first line, you should just be able to read it from `f` before iterating over the csv reader.  (I think).  e.g. `f.readline(); csv_reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')`

Comment: I have heard repeatedly how awesome the StackOverflow community is.  Thanks, and I can't wait to give back one day.